# Verifying that a group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

**Let $(G, *)$ be a group. Suppose that for all $a,b, \in G$, $ab=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Show that $G$ is abelian.**

I tried using the fact that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$, but it became circular. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Hint;  note that every element is its own inverse.  Apply that to $ba$.

Comment: Are you sure the condition isn't “$(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$”?

Answer (score 5):

Let $e$ be the identity. Then taking $b=e$, we get, $$a=a^{-1}$$ for all $a \in G$. Now let $a,b \in G$. Then $$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$$ Hence $G$ is Abelian.

Answer (score 2):

You started correctly. You have $a^{-1 }b^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. But then$$ab=(a^{-1})^{-1}(b^{-1})^{-1}=(b^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=ba.$$